How do I create a Cloud page with dynamic filtering
I'm in the process of building a Cloudpage app for lead handling.
The source DE is about 100k rows.
The users need to be able to use multiple filters simultaneously to narrow down the results.
Is there a way to dynamically add multiple filters to a call in SSJS/ampscript, or would it be better (although a bit heavy) to use wsproxy to pull all rows from the DE and handle the filtering client side?
For example, I've got columns for related campaigns and segments that are both IDs delimited by commas, and I want to be able to filter them if they contain specific values.

Your 3rd statement is the way to go... Retrieve all rows and control filtering at client side script... to retrieve all rows add a boolean field say flag with all values 'True' and fetch using set @lookupDeRows = lookuprows("YourDEName","flag","true")

Both approaches work, so this at some point almost becomes a matter of taste (or which language you are more comfortable with, frontend / backend). When you want to scale, it's a clear decision.
Given you have 100k rows (and that won't grow much), and you are comfortable with frontend side filtering, then you can use (I will write ssjs, get to why later):
var table = "myDeName"
var numberOfRows = 100000
var sortBy = "_CustomObjectKey DESC" //ASC
Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows(table,numberOfRows,sortBy,["isDeleted"],["false"])

You'll see how fast or slow this is by testing, but I found it to surprisingly fast even when raising the numberOfRows.
It will send a very big array, but only once on page load. For one DE of 100k this likely works.
The scaling issue comes when you do it for several arrays - at some point your page will take 30 seconds or longer too load (been there).
This approach is kind of what Vishal commented, but you need lookupOrderedRows for it to go beyond the lookupRows limit of 2000 (or was it 2500?) records. The rest would be frontend.
==
SSJS is useful because it also shows how can make the "filter" statement dynamic, which is the base for an alternative approach.
Dissimilar to AMPScript where the filter is alternating pairs of key/value key/value, in SSJS you get a "array of keys" (["isDeleted"]) / "array of values" (["false"]) structure, which is less annoying to dynamically construct.
So you could use the UI to just build the variables for the lookup and let the backend run "dynamic queries" in SSJS. I've done something similar where the frontend constructs a "config" object  that it sends to backend, and the backend runs many "smaller" lookups using SSJS. This was done to improve page load when the first solution approach just ran into loading times that were unsustainable, as I had done it for too many tables.
backend:
function dynamicLookup(lookupDefinition) {

    var lookupDefinition = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(lookupDefinition)

    var isOrdered = lookupDefinition.isOrdered
    var targetDataExtension = lookupDefinition.targetDataExtension
    var arrayOfFieldNames = lookupDefinition.arrayOfFieldNames
    var arrayOfFieldValues = lookupDefinition.arrayOfFieldValues
    var maxNumberRows = lookupDefinition.maxNumberRows
    var sortedByField = lookupDefinition.sortedByField
    var sortingOrder = lookupDefinition.sortingOrder
    var rowSet = [] 
    if (isOrdered == true) {
        rowSet = Platform.Function.LookupOrderedRows(targetDataExtension,maxNumberRows,sortedByField+" "+ sortingOrder,arrayOfFieldNames,arrayOfFieldValues)
    } else {
        rowSet = Platform.Function.LookupRows(targetDataExtension,arrayOfFieldNames,arrayOfFieldValues)
    }
    return rowSet
}

//get the definition from frontend
var lookupDefinition = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("lookupDefinition")


// run function
if(lookupDefinition) {
   var result = dynamicLookup(lookupDefinition)   
}


And the frontend essentially just builds an object (the "definition") that it sends to the backend on form submit or whatever.
frontend object, this you can construct via any UI:
let myLookupDefinition = {
    isOrdered: true
    ,targetDataExtension: "something the user choose via UI (de name)"
    ,arrayOfFieldNames: ["isDeleted","Type"] // UI ...
    ,arrayOfFieldValues: ["False","Email"] // UI ...
    ,maxNumberRows: 10000 // UI ...
    ,sortedByField: "CreatedDate" // .. .
    ,sortingOrder: "DESC" // you get it 
}


That looks great. I ended up fetching all records but set a limit for low scores to increase performance a bit. This made it possible to add states to handle filter and sorting values which can be reset if wanted without having to do another call. Will see how performance changes when adding an array for campaign info.
